# Javascript | jsPDF y html2canvas - No genera el archivo pdf

Tags: javascript, django

Al utilizar jsPDF y html2canvas y ejecutar, no genera el PDF como debería:
A modo de prueba el primero alert "hola" lo ejecuta, pero no llega al siguiente "hola2".
¿Qué sucede para que genere el pdf?

Gracias.

**Código:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.1.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js" integrity="sha512-jzL0FvPiDtXef2o2XZJWgaEpVAihqquZT/tT89qCVaxVuHwJ/1DFcJ+8TBMXplSJXE8gLbVAUv+Lj20qHpGx+A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function genPDF() {
        alert("hola");
        html2canvas(document.getElementbyId("testDiv"),{
            onrendered: function (canvas){
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',20,20);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
        alert("hola2");
    }

</script>



<body id="testDiv">
<h1>Prueba para crear archivo pdf con este contenido</h1>
</body>
```

No se interpretar la consola, pero muestra lo siguiente:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eOV5.png]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRXqc.png]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa la consola, si hay algún error, edita la pregunta y agrega el mensaje.

Comment: Gracias Triby. No se interpretar bien la consola, pero he añadido lo que muestra. Un saludo.

Comment: No se está cargando el script de _jsPDF_, o bien, el error mostrado `Uncaught SyntaxError: ...` no permite que se ejecute el resto de scripts. A la derecha debe aparecer el nombre de archivo y número de línea que genera el error. Edita la pregunta y agrega el bloque de código (no solo la línea) donde está esa línea.

Comment: Modificaste uno de los errores que te indican en la respuesta. ¿Cambió algo en el resultado o en la consola?

Comment: Hay un error en `propper.min.js` y puede ser el causante de que otros scripts no se ejecuten apropiadamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pagina oficial de [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), viene especificado como acceder a el modulo jsPDF, si no importado como modulo.

El otro error supongo fue al pasar, en tu body pones el id pero asignaste una etiqueta int en lugar de id.

Te dejo el código, como deberías poder acceder y un ejemplo funcional en la siguiente [liga](https://jsfiddle.net/).

```js
  const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
  function genPDF() {
        alert("hola");
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("testDiv"),{
            onrendered: (canvas)=>{
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',20,20);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
        alert("hola2");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.1.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js" integrity="sha512-jzL0FvPiDtXef2o2XZJWgaEpVAihqquZT/tT89qCVaxVuHwJ/1DFcJ+8TBMXplSJXE8gLbVAUv+Lj20qHpGx+A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body id="testDiv">
  <button onclick="genPDF();">genPDF </button>
  <h1>Prueba para crear archivo pdf con este contenido</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Puedes corregir el enlace a jsfiddle, que está apuntando al home del sitio

Comment: No comprendo, disculpa. ¿Te refieres al CDN? ¿No se pone así según la documentación? Gracias.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias.